# How to debug Nuxt in browser scripts via Google Chrom extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

I found many questions about this debugging experience without good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my config for debug in-browser scenarios.
1. Install Debugger for Chrome extension.
2. Add configuration in nuxt.config.js:

```
extend(cfg, ctx) {
  cfg.devtool = 'source-map';
}
```

3. Add launch config:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug Front in Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:YourSitePortHere",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "breakOnLoad": true,
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
}
```

4. Start site: npm run dev (my dev script is default: "dev": "nuxt")
5. Start debug via F5 or in debug panel.
6. Browser will appear with your site and breakpoints in vs code will work when you work in this new browser window!